# Which is the best way to model different types of people and relationships in a database?

Tags: database-design, normalization

I have a scenario where I have two tables, `person_natural` and `person_legal`.

**Case 1:**

I have employees, farmers, customers, and suppliers. Should I have an enum in each table (`person_natural` or `person_legal`) indicating the type of person (for example, in `person_natural` I would have a column called `type` to say if it is an employee, farmer, or customer) or should I create a table for each type of person and link it to the main table using a FK?

I ask this because employees and customers have additional columns, for example, an employee has a salary and a customer has a credit limit. If I put these columns in the main table, the column will always be NULL for a certain type of person.

Example:

```
person_natural
employee -> FK person_natural
farmer -> FK person_natural
customer -> FK person_natural
```

or

```
person_natural -> type_person (employee, farmer, customer)
```

**Case 2:**

I have a table for attachments and a table for addresses. If I have the tables `person_natural` and `person_legal`, I would normally have to create a join table for each one:

```
person_natural
person_natural_attachment
person_natural_address

person_legal
person_legal_attachment
person_legal_address
```

In this case, is it correct (especially following database normalization) to create a table called `person` and leave the FK in `person_natural` and `person_legal` only so as not to have to create additional join tables?

```
person
person_natural -> FK person
person_legal -> FK person
person_attachment
person_address
```

In this case, if I had a `person_natural`, I could easily access the attachments by joining the `person` and then the `person_attachment` tables.

What are the recommended practices for these two scenarios?
I am open to any suggestions or recommendations.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this case, is it correct (especially following database normalization) to create a table called person and leave the FK in person_natural and person_legal only so as not to have to create additional join tables?

Yes, it is correct and necessary for normalization. You will have a [Subtype](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf) cluster as a result (The FK to `person` will also be the PK of `person_natural` and `person_legal`).

- For modeling natural and legal entities, you would most probably need an exclusive subtype, where a **Person** is a **PersonNatural** XOR a **PersonLegal**, so you will need to implement some additional structures and constraints. Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896831/how-to-implement-referential-integrity-in-subtypes/4898314#4898314) for more details.
- Using a similar method you can model the employee, farmer, customer, and supplier subtypes. Maybe in this case a non-exclusive subtype is more appropriate, where a **Person** is at least one of **PersonEmployee**, **PersonFarmer**, **PersonCustomer**, and **PersonSupplier**.

[image]